# vba to create a pivot table excel 2015

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to create a Pivot table in Excel 2015.

I recorded the macros to create my own vba code. But I couldn't make it. Also, I referred the links available here, but I couldn't make it out from them because they followed other way, which was hard for me.

Could anyone help me to frame the VBA code for the below recorded macros and explain in the comment the steps? This would be really helpful for me as I am generating the Pivot table in vba for first time.

```
    Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Preparation sheet!R1C1:R1048576C8", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet21!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable7" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet21").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Category")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Colour")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Category")
        .PivotItems("DG-035583").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DG-048917").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DG-Series").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("gn").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("yl").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Colour")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should at least point out were **exactly** your issue is. "*Create a pivot table*" is not a good description of what you tried to achieve. You need to ask a **specific** question with **detailed** information what is going wrong in your code. Please read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below to create/update a `PivotTable`, explanations inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoPivot()

Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim PvtSht              As Worksheet

' set Pivot Cache for Pivot Table
' Your range is static, there are ways to refer to a dynamic range
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Preparation sheet!R1C1:R1048576C8")

' set the Pivot table's sheet
Set PvtSht = Worksheets("Sheet21")

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable7") ' check if "PivotTable7" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' Pivot table object is nothing >> create it

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable4" sheet
    Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable7")

    With PvtTbl
        With .PivotFields("Category")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Colour")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Category")
            .PivotItems("DG-035583").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("DG-048917").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("DG-Series").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("gn").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("yl").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Colour")
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mikz what is? feel free to ask

Comment: I used the above code and executed it. I get an error application defined or object defined error. How do i overcome this ?

Comment: I am getting the Output perfectly. At the end it Shows this dialogue box . @Shai Rado

Comment: while running through each line also, i am not finding any error. But why do i get this runtime error at the end .? @shai Rado

Comment: @Mikz can you post this as a new question, can you also add some more details, like the name of your sheets, maybe also add a screen-shot of your Pivot-Table after running this code ?

Comment: ya. @Shai Rado, I will do it